# moving numbers starting with

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database of phone numbers (aprox 50k records) in column B and i want to extract all the numbers starting with "07" into column C on the same row.
I have this.

```
          A                B
1    0113 1210012
2    07878 121213
3    01423 568741
4    07584 123123
5    0033 123456789
6    07548 1234567
```

And I need a way of creating this

```
          A                  B
1    0113 1210012
2                       07878 121213
3    01423 568741
4                       07584 123123
5    0033 123456789
6                       07548 1234567
```

Comment: @Viky OP needs to filter out 07 codes into Column B

Comment: You could simply sort the data and copy the 07-Block over by hand. Since this is text, you could also use a "starts with..."-autofilter.

Comment: Use `Autofilter - Begins with` No VBA Code required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA code for you to try: I used the `regex` and `arraylist` object. It's faster to loop through in the code object than doing it with `range` to minimize the traffic between worksheet and code. Plus Not sure if you wanted to output duplicates or uniques only. So I just simply choose ArrayList Against the Dictionary. Also ArrayList allows you to keep the position right ;)

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartingWith07()
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim dc As Object
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrList As Object

Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
objRegex.Global = True
objRegex.Pattern = "^(07)"

'-- you can also use dynamic last row to set the range from A2
vArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("A2:A10").Value)

    For i = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        If objRegex.Test(Trim(vArray(i))) Then
            arrList.Add vArray(i)
        Else
            arrList.Add ""
        End If
    Next i

    '--output to sheet
    Sheets(1).Range("B2").Resize(arrList.Count) = _ 
    Application.Transpose(arrList.toarray())

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Jef please take a look at this code if you really need it to be done via VBA.. However a normal sort by hand would be handy too :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
Sub Filter07()

Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Range

Set MyRange = Range([B1], Cells(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

For Each MyCell In MyRange

    If Left(Trim(Format(MyCell.Value, "@")), 2) = "07" Then

        MyCell(1, 2) = Trim(Format(MyCell.Value, "@"))
        MyCell = ""

    End If

Next MyCell

End Sub
```